# Print tuple of Decimals without the label "Decimal"

Tags: python, list, decimal, pretty-print

I have a `Vector` class as follows:

```
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)
```

If I run the code below...

```
v1 = Vector([1,1])
print v1
```

...I get

```
Vector: (Decimal('1'), Decimal('1'))
```

How can I get rid of the label 'Decimal'?
The output should look like:

```
Vector: (1, 1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Decimal to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093021/python-decimal-to-string)

Comment: I was aware of the str() method, but simply applying it to the tuple did not remove the label 'Decimal'. The combination of the str() and join() methods inside a list comprehension solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `str()` around your decimals works:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from decimal import Decimal

class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: ({})'.format(', '.join(str(x) for x in self.coordinates))

v1 = Vector([1,1])
print(v1)
```

Output:

```
Vector: (1, 1)
```

Comment: Yes, realized this. Improved,

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `str` function:

```
import decimal
d = decimal.Decimal(10)
d
Decimal('10')
str(d)
'10'
```

For your code:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Vector: {}'.format(map(str, self.coordinates))
```

Comment: Never call double-underscore methods directly. This code should be `str(d)`.

Comment: That's not quite the output that the OP wants: it has square brackets instead of round ones, and it has unwanted quote marks around the co-ords. And in Python 3 `map` returns a map object, not a list, so the output will be even more inscrutable.