# How to iterate through elements of a decimal number in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to pass an Integer converted to Decimal in Python. Then I need to check each single digit in the Decimal number if it is odd or even. For example, if integer is 534(it can be any integer though), converted to decimal it is still 534. Now if I try to iterate through this decimal to check if 5 is odd or even, then 3 is odd or even and then 4 is odd or even. If all digits are even, then it is True otherwise False.
When I try to iterate through decimal number, then I get an error "Decimal is not iterable"
Anyway, I created a program which achieves this purpose but I need to convert Decimal to String. Since requirement is to use Decimal so I think my solution is probably not meeting the requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: convert one type to another is common in most language, so i think your code can meet the requirement.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori. Thanks for your comment. I think you are right, this is common. Anyway, I could not find a way to do it without converting Decimal to another type.

Comment: Could you [Convert Decimal to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093021/python-decimal-to-string) and then iterate through the elements?

Answer (score 0):

This is not as neat but as far as I've been able to test it, it seems to work.

A bug fix should remove excess 0's from fraction.

It's getting messy but I have to assume certain input errors will occur and filter them out. Like entering 1. or .1 or 1.1000 for example,

```py
def find_Odd_Even(m):
    try:
        n = list(str( m ))
        if n.count(".") < 2:
            if n.count(".") == 0:
                n.extend([ ".", "0" ])
            elif n.index(".") == len(n) - 1:
                n.append("0")
            b = n.index(".")
            BB = "".join( n[ b+1: ] )
            while len(BB) > 1:
                k = BB.removesuffix("0")
                if k == BB:
                    break
                else:
                    BB = k
            AA = int("".join( n[ :b ] ))
            BB = int( BB )
            if AA&1 == 1 or BB&1 == 1:
                answer = f"{m} is an odd number"
            else:
                answer = f"{m} is an even number"
        else:
            answer = "Bad input"
    except Exception as err:
        answer = str(err)
    finally:
        return answer

while 1:
    m = input("Enter an decimal number: ")
    if m == "":
        break
    else:
        print(find_Odd_Even( m ))
```

Comment: @Thanks Derek but  I want to do it with Decimal number, not with an integer or a string. Requirement is to pass an integer, then convert it into a decimal number and then fulfill the rest of the requirement as mentioned above. Isn't there a way in Python to handle digits of a decimal number? I tried your solution on Decimal number but it does not work.

Comment: Let me change it a little.

Comment: Decimal numbers have a fractional part but integers don't. We need to pass integers. When integers are converted into Decimals in Python (decimal.Decimal as you can see in my code), the number would just look like Integer even though internally it is Decimal. For example, If there is an integer 637, to convert it to decimal. I write the following code: from decimal import Decimal     Decimal(637) would return 637. Both are same. But when I try to use loop or comprehension as you have done above on Decimal number, then it does not work. If any of the digits is odd, then False, else True.

Comment: I've found a bug. A number like 24.1000 will return Even. So a slight modification is needed.